# Create pandas dataframe columns if values in other column satisfy conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I have a dataframe like this:

| index | domain | type | upstream | downstream | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | google | search engine | 1 | 0 | NaN |
| 2 | bbcnews | public broadcaster | 1 | 1 | centre |
| 3 | bbcnews | public broadcaster | 1 | 1 | centre |
| 4 | facebook | social media | 1 | 0 | NaN |
| 5 | foxnews | commercial broadcaster | 1 | 1 | centre |

I want to achieve a dataframe like this:

| index | domain | type | upst | downst | flag | refer_fb | refer_soc_med | ref_goog | refer_search_eng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | google | search engine | 1 | 0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | bbcnews | public broadcaster | 1 | 1 | centre | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | bbcnews | public broadcaster | 1 | 1 | centre | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | facebook | social media | 1 | 0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | foxnews | commercial broadcaster | 1 | 1 | centre | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

What my script needs to do is:

Create new columns, which classify each news item (always flagged as centre) according to the previous row when it satisfies the condition of upstream = 1, downstream = 0. I want binary values in the new columns.

Importantly, if the subsequent row after a 'news' type is also 'news' shown by 'centre' flag, then this should also be classified the same as what the previous news row was classified.

Comment: Have you checked out Pandas' groupby function?

Comment: I would like point out what is there in req df. you must use specific index columns just to make it easy. What you  have written will eventually reduce to only 2 rows if you considering removing duplicates.

Comment: by "previous step" you're referring to the previous row (assuming is sorted)?

Comment: @MateoTorres yes!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating groups based on where social media and search engine rows are in the table with a boolean index and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum). Then get refs based on the first row in each group using [groupby tranform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) 'first'.

`refs`:

```
0    search engine
1    search engine
2     social media
Name: type, dtype: object
```

Then use [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies) to convert `refs` into 1 and 0 indicator values.

```
   search engine  social media
0              1             0
1              1             0
2              0             1
```

[Join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) with the columns in `df` to keep in the new DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'domain': {0: 'google', 1: 'bbcnews', 2: 'bbcnews', 3: 'facebook',
               4: 'foxnews'},
    'type': {0: 'search engine', 1: 'news', 2: 'news', 3: 'social media',
             4: 'news'}, 'upstream': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
    'downstream': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1},
    'flag': {0: np.nan, 1: 'centre', 2: 'centre', 3: np.nan, 4: 'centre'}
})

# Create mask for News Rows
m = df.type.eq('news')
# get first row from each group
refs = df.groupby(
    (~m).cumsum()  # Groups Based on Not News Rows
)['type'].transform('first')[m].reset_index(drop=True)

# Create New DF with columns to keep and the dummies from refs
new_df = df.loc[m, ['domain', 'type']] \
    .reset_index(drop=True) \
    .join(pd.get_dummies(refs)) \
    .rename(columns={'search engine': 'ref_search engine',
                     'social media': 'ref_social media'})

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
    domain  type  ref_search engine  ref_social media
0  bbcnews  news                  1                 0
1  bbcnews  news                  1                 0
2  foxnews  news                  0                 1
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, I can see this is nearly there but am not familiar with some of the methods you use so am struggling to complete. My problem is that I have multiple different types of news (e.g., "Public broadcaster", "tabloid"). Adding them to the mask doesn't work. e.g., mask1 = df.type == "Hyperpartisan media" 
mask2 = df.type == "Quality newspaper/magazine" ... m = mask1 + mask2. Is there way of easily amending the code to enable the different types of news I have to be compatible?

Comment: Use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin):  `m = df.type.isin(['news', 'tabloid'])` etc. As a note for future questions, the fact that there are different 'news' types is something that should be included in the question where possible. Sometimes the best approach can change dramatically when the datatypes or structure changes.